# position clone при drag'n'drop

Tags: jquery, css, drag-n-drop, position

Добрый день. 
Подскажите пожалуйста как изменить положение `helper: 'clone'`?

Дело в том, что при любом scrollX или scrollY, мой 'clone' меняет свое местоположение.
Пример:
[image: клон неверное отображается]

Клон сдвигается именно на равное значение scroll.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как избавиться от зависимости scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась как ни странно очень просто.

в проекте использовалась библиотека - jquery.ui/1.10.3
В библиотеке jquery.ui/1.12.1 этой проблемы уже нет.